# Prevent the overflow of text

Tags: formatting, line-breaking

I'm having some Yiddish text overflow it's box in a XeLaTeX document. I suspect there is a simple command to stop this from happening. Does anyone know an easy solution or do I need to make and post a MWE?

As can be seen in the screenshot it is interfering with my image to the right and causing it to be shifted down.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

for such paragraphs use

```
\begin{sloppypar}
... text ...
\end{sloppypar}
```

Comment: Thanks. But I need a command that will instruct the whole document of about 1800 pages not to do this. So adding it manually would be a bit of an issue. Is there not some command I can place in the preamble?

Comment: \sloppy but that can lead to some lousy formatting. Try it out.