# How to avoid bad box with long words with no hyphenation?

Tags: hyphenation, acronyms

I know there are planty of similar questions, but I haven't found the answer to this particular one.

I have a long word (say some long acronym like ABCDEFGH). It happens to be at the and of the line in the text, going over the margins and creating a bad box.

How can I avoid this, and force the acronym into the new line, but **without breaking it** ?

The concreete example is displayed in the attached image.

[image]

Comment: `\begin{sloppypar}`.... will allow space to strech more and avoid the overfull line

Comment: Sometimes the only (good looking) solution is to change the text, which is not always possible. In your case `Minimal Super Gravity model (mSUGRA)` may helps …

Comment: Since you can do it (it's your own text), I would certainly prefer re-wording the text (as suggested by Tobi) over going sloppy.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Prevent the overflow of text](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/73330/prevent-the-overflow-of-text)

Comment: @Luka: Please note that `sloppypar` produces not a satisfying justification and to wide inter word space (like MS Word does …) and that will decrease the typographical quality of your document ;-)

Comment: or perhaps specify hyphenation for your name - something that gets stuffed into the preamble part of the LaTeX source file.  Tho' this won't work when you don't want to break the  initialism portion, e.g.  "MyFancyNamedThingy(MFNTGATTACAROTFLMAO)"

Answer (score 4):

As David said in the comment it is possible to use `{sloppypar}`

```
\begin{sloppypar}
   Text
\end{sloppypar}
```

This will make LaTeX more careless on good justification and increase the inter-word space. The results often look as ugly as if they are done by MS word.

The preferred solution is rewriting the text in a way that the overfull box(es) disappear, in your case changing the text to

```
Minimal Super Gravity model (mSUGRA)
```

may help without distracting the good justification. Sure this cannot be done always becaus most authors don’t like to see their texts changed by the designer but in cases of author = designer this solution should be tried first!

Comment: Other changes can be done to get rid of this: `The thesis aims to adopt the framework of Minimal Super Gravity (mSUGRA) model` or `The aim of this thesis is the adoption of the framework of  Minimal Super Gravity (mSUGRA) model` etc.